# show categories on left side

Tags: magento2, category, navigation

I'm using this extension https://github.com/Sebwite/magento2-category-sidebar/
I have installed it but I'm struck at a configuration point
It says

You should implement the block Sebwite\Sidebar\Block\Sidebar in your theme to make this extension work. Example

But have no idea where to write it.

Anybody kindly help I'm using magento v2 .

I'm having this file structure
[image]

Comment: have seen the any configuration at admin>Store>configuration section.

Comment: @AmitBera yes there is a section titled Sebwite where i have set default category which i want to show. but where to write this in Sebwite\Sidebar\Block\Sidebar in theme???

Answer (score 2):

You need to create depending on what theme are you using the folder structure as following:

app/design/Magento/*theme_name*/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml where *theme_name* has to be changed with the current active theme ( you can find that from the Magento admin, it's "luma" or "blank" but most likely is "luma"

So your final code for that file should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
            <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" name="catalog.topnav.aside" template="html/topmenu-aside.phtml" ttl="3600" before="-"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Create the following structure for removing the catalog.left nav from Layered navigation

app/design/Magento/theme_name/Magento_LayeredNavigation/layout/catalog_category_view_type_layered.xml and add the following code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="catalog.leftnav" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: i want to show top menu in left side of every page  like in and remove from top like in http://www.banggood.com/ .

Comment: Where to add your first xml code please specify files . I'm new to magento and using magento 2

Comment: ok, use the XML reference for that, also you should remove the main navigation with xml, try with the following code:

Comment: <referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
            <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" name="catalog.topnav.aside" template="html/topmenu-aside.phtml" ttl="3600" before="-"/>
        </referenceContainer>

Comment: where i have to put this code?

Comment: in app/design/Vendor/your-theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml , also set for the <page> node layout="2columns-left" , check the XML in my original answer with the remove syntax also . hope it helps, this is what I did and it worked

Comment: i do have that structure of files . see I'm posting image of file structure

Comment: hey its nice but what it is doing that when i go on any category then on page on left side it shows its sub categories but i want whole navigation menu in left instead of top

Comment: well, there are 2 different blocks there, on Layered navigation categories by default Magento has a catalog.leftnav block, that shows only the categories that are set as anchor and have products that are filtrable. if you want to show the topmenu as I showed you before, you can check the reEdited answer

Comment: the second code is not having any effect

Comment: try to put the <referenceBlock name="catalog.leftnav" remove="true" /> in the defauld.xml from Magento_Theme, for me it worked with the Magento_LayeredNavigation sollution, but who knows, if this helped you, pls mark the answer as sollution, if not, I'll try to help you untill you get around the problem

Comment: thanks for your kind words and efforts ...but it is not affecting still showing top menu when we click on category it shows its sub categories in side bar